# animate react component with transform and transition

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, fadein

I use this inline transform to iterate dynamically over slides

```
<div className="slides" style={{transform: `translate(${currentPosition}%, 0px)`, left: 0}}> {slider} </div>
</div>
```

which is working fine. However I would like to add some fadein to this element on position changing and the following css does not working

**on element slides via css**

```
opacity: 0;
animation: fadein 2s ease-in 1 forwards;
```

here is my fadein animation

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

What I'm missing in this case?

Comment: It works. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3047/)

Comment: yes this works on component init but if I change position on click than does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. That will give you idea how can you apply animations.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentPosition: 0,
      opacity: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
      opacity: 1
    }), 500);
  }

  handleClick() {
    let self = this;
    this.setState({
      opacity: 0
    }, () => setTimeout(() => self.setState({
      opacity: 1
    }), 2000))
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      div className = "slides"
      style = {
        {
          transform: `translate(${this.state.currentPosition}%, 0px)`,
          left: 0,
          opacity: this.state.opacity
        }
      } > Some title to test animation < /div> <
      button onClick = {
        this.handleClick.bind(this)
      } > Click < /button> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

React.render( < Test / > , document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.slides {
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3049/)

Hope it helps.